# How would you save one excel file as 200 different file names quickly?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with a template to be filled out by multiple different users. I want the file to have a name of that specific user. I have a text list with all of the different names.

Is there a way to save my excel template as each of the 200 different names quickly?

I have found some VBA macros but they get some weird errors and I don't know enough VBA to interpret them.

Examples of macros I tried (which may be totally off base)

```
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "Path" & Range("A1:A200").Text & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlNormal, 
Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, 
CreateBackup:=False
```

I have also tried

```
Sub SaveAsA1()
ThisFile = Range("A1").Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Save it once, then copy it. Why do you need 200 identical copies of the same file?

Comment: All 200 users need to have their own copy? Send them a link to the template, put a macro in worksheet_open that will copy the template with their environ(username) to their desired location, close template. Just how I tackle this when need be

Comment: Also, "...they get some weird errors..." - What kind of "weird errors"? You might have to make sure the names are "legal" filenames, and can't save with `:` in them for example... Edit: Wait - are you also *getting back* 200+ files, that you want to update? That's going to be a pain. Can you explain a little more the point of saving the same file hundreds of times, as I think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Look into "how to iterate cells in a range". You can't concatenate `Range("A1:A200").Text` into a single value like this; instead you want to iterate the cells in `Range("A1:A200")` and `SaveAs` using the `currentCell.Text` -- it's not a single-step thing. Warning: saving a file 200 times over is going to take a while though... I agree with the others here, this looks like it's trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command prompt (in Windows) to copy and rename a specific file.

1. Open the "Command Prompt"
2. Change the directory to where you have the file saved:

   cd C:\yourfilepath
3. Use the following command to copy and rename your file:

   copy Original_File.xlsx "New_File_Name_User1.xlsx"

This command will copy your original file once and name it.

For multiple files - you can copy the command in step 3, paste it into excel and make a column of all 200 file names you need:

```
copy Original_File.xlsx "New_File_Name_User1.xlsx"
copy Original_File.xlsx "New_File_Name_User2.xlsx"
copy Original_File.xlsx "New_File_Name_User3.xlsx"
copy Original_File.xlsx "New_File_Name_User4.xlsx"
copy Original_File.xlsx "New_File_Name_User5.xlsx"
...
copy Original_File.xlsx "New_File_Name_User200.xlsx"
```

For step 3, copy all 200 of the commands in your excel file - and paste into the command prompt.

This will then copy your original file 200 times and name them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close with your first code example:

```
Sub Temp()
Dim FileNameArr As Variant, X As Long
FileNameArr = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A200").Text)
For X = LBound(FileNameArr) To UBound(FileNameArr)
    If FileNameArr(X) <> "" Then ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:="Path" & FileNameArr(X) & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlNormal
Next
End Sub
```

Read the range to an array first, then loop the array and save out.

I put an if test in there to make sure the result is not blank before saving though otherwise a blank cell will crash your code. It would also be wise to test against invalide filename characters.